# Overriding Sales Email Template in Magento 2 not working

Tags: magento-2.1, email-templates, order-email

I am overriding Sales Order Email to changing the position of **Billing Info** and **Shipping Info**, But it is not working.

**app/design/frontend/[Vendor_Name]/[Theme_Name]/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new.html**

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!--@subject {{trans "Your %store_name order confirmation" store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}} @-->
<!--@vars {
"var formattedBillingAddress|raw":"Billing Address",
"var order.getEmailCustomerNote()":"Email Order Note",
"var order.increment_id":"Order Id",
"layout handle=\"sales_email_order_items\" order=$order area=\"frontend\"":"Order Items Grid",
"var payment_html|raw":"Payment Details",
"var formattedShippingAddress|raw":"Shipping Address",
"var order.getShippingDescription()":"Shipping Description",
"var shipping_msg":"Shipping message"
} @-->

{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<table>
    <tr class="email-intro">
        <td>
            <p class="greeting">{{trans "%customer_name," customer_name=$order.getCustomerName()}}</p>
            <p>
                {{trans "Thank you for your order from %store_name." store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}}
                {{trans "Once your package ships we will send you a tracking number."}}
                {{trans 'You can check the status of your order by <a href="%account_url">logging into your account</a>.' account_url=$this.getUrl($store,'customer/account/',[_nosid:1]) |raw}}
            </p>
            <p>
                {{trans 'If you have questions about your order, you can email us at <a href="mailto:%store_email">%store_email</a>' store_email=$store_email |raw}}{{depend store_phone}} {{trans 'or call us at <a href="tel:%store_phone">%store_phone</a>' store_phone=$store_phone |raw}}{{/depend}}.
                {{depend store_hours}}
                    {{trans 'Our hours are <span class="no-link">%store_hours</span>.' store_hours=$store_hours |raw}}
                {{/depend}}
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-summary">
        <td>
            <h1>{{trans 'Your Order <span class="no-link">#%increment_id</span>' increment_id=$order.increment_id |raw}}</h1>
            <p>{{trans 'Placed on <span class="no-link">%created_at</span>' created_at=$order.getCreatedAtFormatted(2) |raw}}</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="email-information">
        <td>
            {{depend order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}
            <table class="message-info">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()|escape|nl2br}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{/depend}}
            <table class="order-details">
                 <tr>
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3 style="font-weight: bold;">{{trans "Shipping Info"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedShippingAddress|raw}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h3 style="font-weight: bold;">{{trans "Billing Info"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var formattedBillingAddress|raw}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h3>{{trans "Payment Method"}}</h3>
                        {{var payment_html|raw}}
                    </td>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h3>{{trans "Shipping Method"}}</h3>
                        <p>{{var order.getShippingDescription()}}</p>
                        {{if shipping_msg}}
                        <p>{{var shipping_msg}}</p>
                        {{/if}}
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order area="frontend"}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

But it is not changed the position, see below pic.

[image]

Any help? For changing the position of **Billing Info** and **Shipping Info**.

Comment: Just updated my answer. please check and let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your override file path is incorrect.

You have to just override order_new.html file at below location.

```
app/design/frontend/[Vendor_Name]/[Theme_Name]/Magento_Sales/email/order_new.html
```

Clear Cache.

Comment: I moved the file location to your given path. still not working.

Comment: please run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy command and remove var folder

Comment: Sorry i have add sales folder before order_new.html file i have just removed sales folder and you have to follow updated answer path and after changes your issue resolved. You have to remove sales folder.

Comment: Yes, I saw that  it's a wrong path. Now Updated and working fine. Thank You.

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya store_name value not getting in shipment_new.html https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/208776/50730

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do the thing  from admin.

First goto ***Admin>Marketing>Email Templates***

Then created **new template** by Select  Default ***Template*** and click on ***Load template***

[image]
Then on ***Template Content***  your need to change **on your template content**

Then click on ***Save Template*** button  in order save this template

After that you need assign that template at *`Store>Configuration>Sales>Sales Email`* at **New Order Confirmation Template**

[image]

require to do same thing for ***`New Order Confirmation Template for Guess`***

Comment: I have did same thing for Reset Password, But my custom email template not called. Can you please tell me what I missing?